# XCode 8 freezes when hitting breakpoint, never highlights it, have to force quit

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When I'm running debugging my iOS app on-device, some breakpoints never get hit - instead, when the app freezes (as if the breakpoint *has* been hit), but XCode also totally freezes and I have to Force Quit and restart. It happens consistently - the breakpoints that fail fail every time, and those that work, work every time... but I'm struggling to find any rhyme or reason what the difference is.

Does anyone have any hints on steps I can take to further debug this issue?

Comment: How is memory usage of Xcode and your app before hitting the breakpoint?

Comment: Looks like it jumps up from 149MB to 155MB. But then drops back down to 147MB.

Comment: And Xcode memory usage? Consider opening a bug report.

Comment: Do you have sanitizers enabled?

Comment: Please file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com.  We'll need to gather some logs etc. to figure this out, and that's a better mechanism for this sort of traffic.